# jar file will not be packed when put under sub-folder of Assets/Plugins/Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I wrote a `.jar` lib for Unity Android, It could work when I put it under `Assets/Plugins/Android/` folder, but since there will be multi jar files it will be mess if we put all the `jars` in the folder so I decided to put the jar file in a   subfolder for better maintenance, like `Assets/Plugins/Android/gdt/` like that.

But when it was put in that folder, things will not work and the jar file will not be packed under that folder and yields a 'Class Not Found' exception in runtime.

Could I put my jar(s) in a sub-folder under the `Assets/Plugins/Android/` folder?

Comment: `Assets/{APlugin}/Plugin/Android/xxx.jar`
`Assets/{BPlugin}/Plugin/Android/xxx.jar`
Possible you can put like this.
jars also under `Android/` , But you can create mutil `Android/` forlder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidAARPlugins.html) link:

> Unity treats any subfolder of Assets/Plugins/Android as a potential
>   Android Library, and disables Asset importing from within these
>   subfolders. The subfolder is recognized as an Android Library if it
>   contains the AndroidManifest.xml file, and the project.properties file
>   contains the string android.library=true.

Sounds like you need an `AndroidManifest.xml` and project.properties file with `android.library=true` in your subfolder.